# Displaying attributes in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've trying to display the attributes from size in woocommerce.

I'm using

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms("pa_size");
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo "<p>. $term->name .</p>";
?>
```

However it just seems to break the page for some reason.

Full code

```
<div class="titleSP">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<div class="priceSP">

<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>

<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />

</div>


<?php

//code to pull in the attrs

$terms = get_terms("pa_size");
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo "<p>. $term->name .</p>";
?>

<?php if($post->post_excerpt) { ?>
<div class="descriptionSP short">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What error you got ? What kind of breaking page ? Can you describe that.

Comment: Everything on the page seems to stop loading. images loading by js just get the loading icon and nothing appeears.

Comment: Not sure, but did you mean `echo "<p>". $term->name ."</p>";` instead ? Note that I added closing and opening quotes. Also, where did `$post` come from ?

Comment: that part pulls in the short description of the product.